# Разбор слова по составу, непроизводное слово

Tags: морфемный-разбор

Если слово непроизводное, при указании корня нужно подбирать однокоренные слова? Допустим, в слове широкий, если придерживаться Тихонова, корень широк. Тогда, рассматривая этот вариант, можно приводить как однокоренные ширина, широта, которые являются производными от широкий и имеют корень шир? Если нет, то подбирать такие слова, как наречие широко, прилагательные шириколиственный, широкообразованный?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Корень - это **общая часть** родственных слов, в которой заключено их **основное лексическое** значение. Слова с одним и тем же корнем называются однокоренными (родственными).

Широкий - непроизводное слово (лексическое значение -  имеющий большую протяжённость в поперечнике), от него образуются однокоренные слова ширь, широта, ширина, ширить, но при образовании этих слов происходит усечение основы на формант ОК: шир/ок/ий - ширь, шир/ок/ий - шир/ин/а.

Тогда можно считать, что корень ШИРОК/ШИР имеет два морфа с одним значением и все эти слова являются однокоренными.

Но как всё это следует излагать в школьной практике - трудно сказать.

Answer (score 0):

> *Допустим, в слове широкий, если придерживаться Тихонова, корень широк*

У Тихонова слишком утилитарный взгляд на вещи. 
Конечно, школьникам трудно понять, что у "шире" и "широкий" общий морф и общее значение.  )))

Тут вот какая штука. Привязываясь у идее, что однокоренные слова объединены общим значением, мы совершенно теряемся перед исторической грамматикой, которая убедительно показывает, что значения у однокоренных слов могут расходиться настолько, что и опознать-то корень сложно.

Для школьной практики, думаю, в подобных случаях будет ограничиться кругом наиболее близких пл значению слов (похоже, Тихонов так и поступает). Непроизводность основы тут, видимо, вторична.

В таких случаях помогает представление, что "родственность" и "один корень" - вещи разные. Другой стороной этой же медали является понимание разницы диахронического и синхронического подхода в морфологии. Последний предполагает, что исторически однокоренные слова могут утратить родственность и разойтись по разным гнездам. И вот в таком виде, по факту актуального состояния, и надо фиксировать их в  словарях.

А что, нечто подобное включено в ЕГЭ?

Я совсем не специалист по школьным заморочкам, не будут настаивать на свонём взгляде на вещи...

Comment: *У Тихона слишком* - фамилию поправьте.